# How to perform an action after 2 select boxes have been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select boxes. Is there a way to perform an action after both have been selected?

I want the user to select a starting point and a destination from the 2 select boxes and once both values have been selected then I want to display a price.

```
<label>Suburb</label>
<select id="delivery_from_area" name="delivery[from_area]"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">Atlantic Seaboard</option>
<option value="2">City Bowl</option></select>

<label>Suburb</label>
<select id="delivery_to_area" name="delivery[to_area]"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">Atlantic Seaboard</option>
<option value="2">City Bowl</option></select>
```

My attempt

```
    $("#delivery_from_area").on("change",function(){
         var check1 = $("#delivery_from_area").text();
         var check2 = $("#delivery_to_area").text();
         if(check1!="" && check2!="") {
            var value1 = $("#delivery_from_area option:selected").text();
            var value2 = $("#delivery_to_area option:selected").text();
            //calculate value
        }
   });

$("#delivery_to_area").on("change",function(){
         var check1 = $("#delivery_from_area").text();
         var check2 = $("#delivery_to_area").text();
         if(check1!="" && check2!="") {
            var value1 = $("#delivery_from_area option:selected").text();
            var value2 = $("#delivery_to_area option:selected").text();
            //calculate value
        }
   });
```

Comment: Please include some attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: IMO add `disabled selected` to your default option, that way, anytime the user changes the option it will be a valid choice.

Comment: Im stumped. My javascript knowledge is very limited. I just need a starting point - to head in the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have two event listener, one for each select. When one of the events is triggered you just confirm if the other already has a value and if it does then you display the price, if not you ignore and wait for other action.

Example:

```
  $("#select1").on("change",function(){
             var value1 = $(this).val();
             var value2 = $("#select2").val();
             if(value2!="" && value1!="") //Check if are both selected
                     //do your stuff
       });
```

Working example: [jsfiddle.net/pnFx6](http://jsfiddle.net/pnFx6)

Comment: @spuggy If you're still having problems, I got here a working example http://jsfiddle.net/pnFx6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#delivery_to_area").on("change",function(){
    if($('#delivery_from_area').text()=='Select' && $('#delivery_to_area').text=='Select')
    {
        alert("please select value in drop down");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Your calculated value");
    }
});
```